# Create an html table using nested json data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, html-table

I have a dynamic nested JSON data structure, I would like to create a table in HTML, I've tried it in some ways but to no avail, I don't have much knowledge of data manipulation, I couldn't get any results but the data is missing attached is what I need.

```js
{
  "CAIXA DE GORDURA": {
  "PROJETO": {
   "ADEQUADO":"Evidenciou-se um bom índice de retenção de gordura no sistema* Recomenda-se que limpezas periódicas sejam realizadas na caixa de gordura, impedindo sua saturação e posterior incorporação do resíduo ao efluente submetido ao tratamento biológico*",
   "SUBDIMENSIONADO":"Foi possível constatar um certo grau de saturação no sistema* Recomenda-se que limpezas periódicas sejam realizadas na caixa de gordura, impedindo sua saturação e posterior incorporação do resíduo ao efluente submetido ao tratamento biológico*"
  }
 },
 "GRADEAMENTO": {
  "CONDIÇÕES": {
   "LIMPA":"O gradeamento se encontra em condições normais de operação*",
   "PARCIALMENTE OBSTRUÍDA":"Foi observada uma certa quantia de sólidos grosseiros retidos no gradeamento* O técnico responsável pela manutenção realizou a limpeza da etapa deixando em normais condições* Recomenda-se limpezas periódicas no gradeamento impedindo sua total obstrução, e consequentemente o direcionamento de sólidos grosseiros as etapas subsequentes podendo causae entupimentos nas tubulações e avarias aos equipamentos eletromecânicos*",
   "OBSTRUÍDA":"Foi observada uma grande  quantia de sólidos grosseiros retidos no gradeamento* O técnico responsável pela manutenção realizou a limpeza da etapa deixando em normais condições*  Recomenda-se limpezas periódicas no gradeamento impedindo sua total obstrução, e consequentemente o direcionamento de sólidos grosseiros as etapas subsequentes podendo causae entupimentos nas tubulações e avarias aos equipamentos eletromecânicos*"
  },
  "PRESENÇA DE GORDURA": {
   "LIMPA & SIM":"O gradeamento se encontra em condições normais de operação* Não evidencio - se a presença de sólidos grosseiros, porem foi notada a presença de escuma que podem dar indícios de saturação na caixa de gordura*",
   "PARCIALMENTE OBSTRUÍDA & SIM":"Foi observada uma certa quantia de sólidos grosseiros retidos no gradeamento* Porem foi notada a presença de escuma que podem dar indícios de saturação na caixa de gordura* O técnico responsável pela manutenção realizou a limpeza da etapa deixando em normais condições* Recomenda-se limpezas periódicas no gradeamento impedindo sua total obstrução, e consequentemente o direcionamento de sólidos grosseiros as etapas subsequentes podendo causae entupimentos nas tubulações e avarias aos equipamentos eletromecânicos*",
   "OBSTRUÍDA & SIM":"Foi observada uma grande  quantia de sólidos grosseiros retidos no gradeamento* Porem foi notada a presença de escuma que podem dar indícios de saturação na caixa de gordura* O técnico responsável pela manutenção realizou a limpeza da etapa deixando em normais condições*  Recomenda-se limpezas periódicas no gradeamento impedindo sua total obstrução, e consequentemente o direcionamento de sólidos grosseiros as etapas subsequentes podendo causae entupimentos nas tubulações e avarias aos equipamentos eletromecânicos*"
  }
 },
 "CESTO": {
  "CONDIÇÕES": {
   "LIMPA":"O gradeamento se encontra em condições normais de operação*",
   "PARCIALMENTE OBSTRUÍDA":"Foi observada uma certa quantia de sólidos grosseiros retidos no gradeamento* O técnico responsável pela manutenção realizou a limpeza da etapa deixando em normais condições* Recomenda-se limpezas periódicas no gradeamento impedindo sua total obstrução, e consequentemente o direcionamento de sólidos grosseiros as etapas subsequentes podendo causae entupimentos nas tubulações e avarias aos equipamentos eletromecânicos*",
   "OBSTRUÍDA":"Foi observada uma grande  quantia de sólidos grosseiros retidos no gradeamento* O técnico responsável pela manutenção realizou a limpeza da etapa deixando em normais condições*  Recomenda-se limpezas periódicas no gradeamento impedindo sua total obstrução, e consequentemente o direcionamento de sólidos grosseiros as etapas subsequentes podendo causae entupimentos nas tubulações e avarias aos equipamentos eletromecânicos*"
  },
  "PRESENÇA DE GORDURA": {
   "LIMPA & SIM":"O gradeamento se encontra em condições normais de operação* Não evidencio - se a presença de sólidos grosseiros, porem foi notada a presença de escuma que podem dar indícios de saturação na caixa de gordura*",
   "PARCIALMENTE OBSTRUÍDA & SIM":"Foi observada uma certa quantia de sólidos grosseiros retidos no gradeamento* Porem foi notada a presença de escuma que podem dar indícios de saturação na caixa de gordura* O técnico responsável pela manutenção realizou a limpeza da etapa deixando em normais condições* Recomenda-se limpezas periódicas no gradeamento impedindo sua total obstrução, e consequentemente o direcionamento de sólidos grosseiros as etapas subsequentes podendo causae entupimentos nas tubulações e avarias aos equipamentos eletromecânicos*",
   "OBSTRUÍDA & SIM":"Foi observada uma grande  quantia de sólidos grosseiros retidos no gradeamento* Porem foi notada a presença de escuma que podem dar indícios de saturação na caixa de gordura* O técnico responsável pela manutenção realizou a limpeza da etapa deixando em normais condições*  Recomenda-se limpezas periódicas no gradeamento impedindo sua total obstrução, e consequentemente o direcionamento de sólidos grosseiros as etapas subsequentes podendo causae entupimentos nas tubulações e avarias aos equipamentos eletromecânicos*"
  }
 },
 "ELEVATÓRIA DE ENTRADA": {
  "LIMPA FOSSA": {
   "SIM":"Evidenciou-se uma camada espessa de escuma e sólidos sobrenadantes no interior do reservatório* Recomenda-se realizar a limpeza com auxilio de caminhão a vácuo impedindo que os resíduos sejam recalcados ao reatores saturando os mesmos",
   "NÃO":"O efluente no inteiro do reservatório não apresentou sólidos sobrenadantes e0x5Cou escuma de gordura em sua composição*",
   "NA PRÓXIMA VISITA":"De acordo com o manual do fabricante limpezas periódicas (a cada 6 meses) necessitam ser realizadas com intuito de retirar o lodo sedimentado no fundo reestabelecendo a seção hidráulica e o TDH (tempo de detenção hidráulica) nas etapas de tratamento*"
  },
  "SENSOR DE NÍVEL": {
   "CONDIÇÕES NORMAIS":"O funcionamento dos sensores de nível (tipo boia) apresentaram condições normais de funcionamento*",
   "ANOMALIA":"Realizando teste de comutação das bombas submersíveis para analisar a operação das boias foi possível constatar que não se apresentou um funcionamento adequado* Recomendasse que seja realizada a substituição da boia*"
  }
 },
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, after a long search and many attempts I managed to do what I needed using Object.entries (), it returns an array with positions, so I could assemble the table.

```js
{
            Object.entries(data).map((line, index) => (
              <>
                <TableRow key={line[0]} style={{backgroundColor:'#00ff14'}}>
                  <TableCell colSpan='2' component='th' align='center'>
                    {line[0].replace(/([*])/g, '.')}
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
                {Object.entries(line[1]).map((child, index) => (
                  <>
                    <TableRow key={child[0]} style={{backgroundColor:'#00ff14'}}>
                      <TableCell colSpan='2' component='th' align='center'>
                        {child[0].replace(/([*])/g, '.')}
                      </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                    {Object.entries(child[1]).map((child2, index) => (
                      <>
                        <TableRow key={child2[0]}>
                          <TableCell align='right'>
                            {child2[0].replace(/([*])/g, '.').replace(/((?:0x5C))/g, '/')}
                          </TableCell>
                          <Tooltip title={helpText} enterDelay={500} leaveDelay={200} placement="top">
                          <TableCell
                          className={classes.TableCell}
                          onDoubleClick={(e) => handleOpen(e.target.firstChild.nodeValue, child2[0], line[0])}
                          >
                          {child2[1].replace(/([*])/g, '.').replace(/((?:0x5C))/g, '/')}
                          </TableCell>
                          </Tooltip>
                        </TableRow>
                      </>                    
                    ))}
                  </>                  
                ))}
              </>
            ))
          }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using React? It wasn't clear your question was about React, and this is clearly React code.

Comment: yes i'm using react but this is generic i could do this with html normally